# How to add a TODO item in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, to-do

I am working on a longer document in Word, and I would like to add TODO notes that I can review and work on. I googled a little and apparently, such a function exists. According to [this report](https://office-watch.com/2018/word-gets-a-to-do-list-at-long-last/), I only have to type `TODO:` or `<<to do something here>>` and Word automatically creates a TODO item.

This does not work- I have also tried adding a comment and writing TODO in there, also without any success. I also tried using @MyName to tag myself hoping that would give me TODO options, but that didn't do anything either.

Is this a feature I have to enable somewhere? I am using Office 365 on Mac.

Comment: You could try [this version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-a-checklist-in-word-dd04fa4f-2ca7-4543-8818-c469eca9f45c), which uses the Developer Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the feature was dropped. Here is the 2022 writeup of the original article @FlonLon referred to https://office-watch.com/2022/word-gets-a-to-do-list-at-long-last/

I would have loved this feature. I am trying to use Word instead of OneNote so that I can place the notes (word document) together with other artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

From the View tab on ribbon, mark the checkbox for the Navigation Pane. You can also open the sidebar from the Menu Bar > View > Sidebars.

On the Sidebar there is a Check icon and selecting it will show the follow-up items you have entered into the document.

To add Follow Up items to a document, type a double bracket like this: {{

A display field opens for you to type in your follow up reminder. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: There is no check item in my navigation pane. I assume this is because I don't have any follow-up items yet. Typing "{{" did not open a display field for me.

Comment: What is your version number of Word? You can locate that from Word > About

Comment: 16.43 (20110804)

Comment: If you are not seeing the Check icon on the Navigation Pane, then you probably need to join the Insider program on Office for Mac if you want this feature right now. The Insider program offers use of pre-released versions of the product.

Comment: I selected Beta, and am now at version 16.45 (20120106), and still nothing works. Is there some documentation of what version is required?

Comment: Being in the insider program essentially means volunteering to be an unpaid beta tester for the new releases. Read through the terms and conditions before signing up.

Comment: I've not seen any documentation on this feature and I have sent a note into my Microsoft contacts on the Mac team to see what they have. Another thing to try is logging into OneDrive. It doesn't appear that the document has to be on OneDrive but I'm just wondering if Word needs to see that it could connect.

Comment: The Follow-up or check item is not in the standard nor insider desktop application in Windows. It is in the online, web version

Comment: I have heard back from Microsoft, on the Mac, this feature is only currently available for Insiders Preview. Since you have moved up to the Insider release, try restarting your system and let's see if you can then access it.